# Regular expression to replace value of ID field in mysql insert query

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to change the ID of the following  script with a regular expression in notepad++.

Example:

```
Insert into AAAAA
   (ID, A, B, C)
 Values
   (1234, dasdas, fdasdsa, FSD);
```

After regular expresion:

```
Insert into AAAAA
   (ID, A, B, C)
 Values
   (sequence, dasdas, fdasdsa, FSD);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you face this kind of problem, you should start by explaining (to yourself) how one could identify the ID part. To write the regular expression, you must first formulate necessary and sufficient conditions for actually finding the string. Also, explaining them would make it a lot easier to help you, since we would not be guessing what is variable in your example.

The ID seems to be the only number that follows an opening bracket. A matching regular expression would be:

```
/\(\d+/
```

To replace with:

```
(sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Notepad++ here but this may work:

replace

`(.*Values \()(\d+)(.* )` with

`\1sequence\3`

Comment: either change `(.*Values \()(?:\d+)(.* )` or `\1sequence\3`